# Pasar parámetros React native

Tags: react-native

Estoy utilizando un Flatlist para mostrar los datos de una tabla que tengo en un hosting y al momento de darle clic a uno de los botones me envié a otra pestaña donde me mande el id y la información  que pase según corresponda con sigo misma ¿Como puedo hacer esto?

````
      <View>
        <View style={styles.cuadro}>
        <View style={styles.row}>
            <View style={styles.Izquierda}>
            <Image
        style={{width:200,
            height:180}}
        source={require('../../DiseñoDinamico/img/Hotel.png')}
      />
        <Text>Estrellas {item.Estrellas}
        </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.Derecha}>
        <Text style={{fontSize:40}}>{item.Nombre}</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hotel de {item.Estrellas} Estrellas</Text>
        <Text style={{fontSize:15}}>Dir: {item.Direccion}</Text>
        <Text>Tel: {item.Telefono}</Text>
                <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('Reservacion',item.idHotel)}><Text style={{textAlign:'right',fontSize:30}} >Reservar una habitacion</Text></TouchableOpacity>
         
        </View>
        </View>  
        </View>
      <Text> </Text>
      </View>
        }/>```
````

Comment: Podrías utilizar REDUX para que esos datos puedan obtenerse en cualquier lugar de la aplicación.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aportación pero termine utilizando getparam de navigation, no me percate que había actualizado el método y envés de utilizar getparam("","") se utilizaba source

Answer (score 0):

lo solucione utilizando getparam

```
<FlatList  data={this.state.dataSource} renderItem={({item}) => 
  <View>
    <View style={styles.cuadro}>
    <View style={styles.row}>
        <View style={styles.Izquierda}>
        <Image
    style={{width:200,
        height:180}}
    source={require('../../DiseñoDinamico/img/Hotel.png')}
  />
    <Text>Estrellas {item.Estrellas}
    </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.Derecha}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:40}}>{item.Nombre}</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize:20}}>Hotel de {item.Estrellas} Estrellas</Text>
    <Text style={{fontSize:15}}>Dir: {item.Direccion}</Text>
    <Text>Tel: {item.Telefono}</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity  onPress={() =>this.props.navigation.navigate('Reservacion', {  
        idHotel: item.Estrellas,  
        otherParam: '101',  
    })  
}  ><Text style={{textAlign:'right',fontSize:30}} >Reservar una habitacion</Text></TouchableOpacity>
     
    </View>
    </View>  
    </View>
  <Text> </Text>
  </View>
    }/>
```

mandando la id de hotel hacia  reservación

```
render() {  
    {/*Using the navigation prop we can get the 
          value passed from the previous screen*/}  
    
    const id_Hotel = this.props.route.params.idHotel
      
    return (  
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>  
            <Text style={{ marginTop: 16,fontSize: 20,}}>  
                Hotel 
            </Text>  
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>Hotel: {JSON.stringify(id_Hotel)}</Text>  
            <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>  
            <Button  
                title="Go back"  
                onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}  
            />  
            </View>  
        </View>  
    );  
}
```

}